# Web Scraping : Yahoo provides dirtyurl instead of normal url

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, yahoo

I'm using mechanize to get the top results from yahoo search and scrape data from them, but yahoo provides only dirtyurls, which gives error on further processing, any solution to obtain original link?

example: For the result stackoverflow.com, I get the following tag

`<a  dirtyhref="http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0SO8zEuKGZUteYAEHRXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEzODh2cDk0BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2dxMQR2dGlkA1ZJUDI0NF8x/RV=2/RE=1416009903/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f/RK=0/RS=a.mWRIy6IMjJQysgixByd8053hE-"  id="link-1" class="yschttl spt" href="http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0SO8zEuKGZUteYAEHRXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEzODh2cDk0BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2dxMQR2dGlkA1ZJUDI0NF8x/RV=2/RE=1416009903/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f/RK=0/RS=a.mWRIy6IMjJQysgixByd8053hE-" target="_blank" data-bk="5054.1"> <b>Stack Overflow</b> - Official Site </a>`

So here
http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0SO8zEuKGZUteYAEHRXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEzODh2cDk0BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2dxMQR2dGlkA1ZJUDI0NF8x/RV=2/RE=1416009903/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f/RK=0/RS=a.mWRIy6IMjJQysgixByd8053hE-

represents http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can isolate easily the content of `dirtyhref` (you can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the link, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you can use the `urlparse` package to get only the path (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse). Now you'll have it in a string like:

```
dirty_href = "/_ylt=A0SO8zEuKGZUteYAEHRXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEzODh2cDk0BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2dxMQR2dGlkA1ZJUDI0NF8x/RV=2/RE=1416009903/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f/RK=0/RS=a.mWRIy6IMjJQysgixByd8053hE-"\
```

Now, it looks to me that fields are separated by `/`, so you can:

```
fields = dirty_href.split('/')
```

Assuming that the fields you are interested in is always the sixth:

```
dirty_url = fields[5].split('=')[1]
```

Finally, you can use `unquote` from the `urllib2` package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

```
>>> urllib2.unquote(dirty_url)
'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```

You can also not assume that the URL will always be in the sixth field, by cycling over `fields` and check if it starts with `RU=`.

Comment: Upon using this repeatedly, I've fond that the index 5 is not the same all the time, So I'd like to add this to @Mikk 's answer, in case anyone else needs it`for part in fields: if part.startswith('RU='):
url = urllib2.unquote(str(part).split('=')[1])`